# All-or-none exclusive lock on 2 SQL tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, locking, deadlock

My simplistic testing suggested that I can acquire an exclusive lock on 2 tables or postpone acquiring the lock on either until both can be acquired at once by using a query like this:

```
SELECT AutoKey, OnHand FROM ONNM(XLOCK) CROSS JOIN OITM(XLOCK)
WHERE ObjectCode IN ('20', '10000048') AND ItemCode = @ItemCode
```

the key feature being the CROSS JOIN used to include multiple tables in a single query. I confirmed that if an exclusive lock already exists on the OITM row for @ItemCode in another transaction, then this statement doesn't introduce any lock on ONNM until it can acquire both locks. However, in the more complex full test run, SQL profiler returns some conflicting information. I have imported the SQL profiler results into a table and executed the following query:

```
select rownum, e.name, EventClass, TextData, SPID, ClientProcessID from #pmit t
join sys.trace_events e on t.EventClass = e.trace_event_id
where rownum between 275799 and 546130
and (TextData LIKE '(ca73a6396124)' or TextData LIKE '(36fa3e654c8f)'
     or TextData LIKE '%(XLOCK)%' or TextData LIKE '%DeadLock%')
order by rownum
```

And these are the results I got back:

```
Row    | Event                | SPID | Text
275799 | SP:StmtStarting      | 99   | SELECT AutoKey, OnHand FROM ONNM(XLOCK) CROSS JOIN OITM(XLOCK) WHERE ObjectCode IN ('20', '10000048') AND ItemCode = @ItemCode
304781 | Lock:Acquired        | 139  | (36fa3e654c8f)
305365 | Lock:Acquired        | 139  | (36fa3e654c8f)
351093 | Lock:Acquired        | 139  | (ca73a6396124)
468768 | Lock:Released        | 13   | (ca73a6396124)
470912 | Lock:Released        | 13   | (36fa3e654c8f)
470922 | Lock:Acquired        | 164  | (36fa3e654c8f)
470928 | Lock:Released        | 164  | (36fa3e654c8f)
470971 | Lock:Acquired        | 99   | (36fa3e654c8f)
471013 | RPC:Completed        | 99   | exec sp_executesql N'SELECT AutoKey, OnHand FROM ONNM(XLOCK) CROSS JOIN OITM(XLOCK) WHERE ObjectCode IN (''20'', ''10000048'') AND ItemCode = @ItemCode',N'@ItemCode nvarchar(3)',@ItemCode=N'FX1'
490843 | SP:StmtStarting      | 78   | SELECT AutoKey, OnHand FROM ONNM(XLOCK) CROSS JOIN OITM(XLOCK) WHERE ObjectCode IN ('20', '10000048') AND ItemCode = @ItemCode
490848 | Lock:Acquired        | 78   | (ca73a6396124)
495391 | Lock:Acquired        | 114  | (36fa3e654c8f)
495396 | Lock:Acquired        | 114  | (36fa3e654c8f)
542738 | Lock:Deadlock Chain  | 6    | Deadlock Chain SPID = 78 (36fa3e654c8f)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
545746 | Lock:Deadlock Chain  | 6    | Deadlock Chain SPID = 154 (36fa3e654c8f)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
545769 | Lock:Deadlock Chain  | 6    | Deadlock Chain SPID = 114 (ca73a6396124)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
545982 | Lock:Deadlock        | 78   | (36fa3e654c8f)
545985 | RPC:Completed        | 78   | exec sp_executesql N'SELECT AutoKey, OnHand FROM ONNM(XLOCK) CROSS JOIN OITM(XLOCK) WHERE ObjectCode IN (''20'', ''10000048'') AND ItemCode = @ItemCode',N'@ItemCode nvarchar(3)',@ItemCode=N'FC3'
545990 | Lock:Released        | 78   | (ca73a6396124)
545998 | Lock:Acquired        | 114  | (ca73a6396124)
546130 | Deadlock graph       | 17   | (See below)
```

The deadlock graph is as follows:

```
<deadlock-list>
   <deadlock victim="process5e3ae08">
      <process-list>
         <process id="process5e3ae08" taskpriority="0" logused="0" waitresource="KEY: 6:72057598620205056 (36fa3e654c8f)" waittime="9507" ownerId="513854688" transactionname="user_transaction" lasttranstarted="2012-06-28T13:38:54.463" XDES="0x1bbf9b950" lockMode="RangeX-X" schedulerid="6" kpid="13248" status="suspended" spid="78" sbid="0" ecid="0" priority="0" trancount="1" lastbatchstarted="2012-06-28T13:38:54.483" lastbatchcompleted="2012-06-28T13:38:54.463" clientapp=".Net SqlClient Data Provider" hostname="PMIUSRSTL00013" hostpid="3180" loginname="RICFSE01SAPB1" isolationlevel="serializable (4)" xactid="513854688" currentdb="6" lockTimeout="4294967295" clientoption1="671088672" clientoption2="128056">
            <executionStack>
               <frame procname="adhoc" line="1" stmtstart="46" sqlhandle="0x02000000151c651e3c8b4437ee414cefdbc46b70aceca960">  SELECT AutoKey, OnHand FROM ONNM(XLOCK) CROSS JOIN OITM(XLOCK) WHERE ObjectCode IN (&apos;20&apos;, &apos;10000048&apos;) AND ItemCode = @ItemCode     </frame>
               <frame procname="unknown" line="1" sqlhandle="0x000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000">  unknown     </frame>
            </executionStack>
            <inputbuf>  (@ItemCode nvarchar(3))SELECT AutoKey, OnHand FROM ONNM(XLOCK) CROSS JOIN OITM(XLOCK) WHERE ObjectCode IN (&apos;20&apos;, &apos;10000048&apos;) AND ItemCode = @ItemCode    </inputbuf>
         </process>
         <process id="process5e45048" taskpriority="0" logused="0" waitresource="KEY: 6:72057598620205056 (36fa3e654c8f)" waittime="12866" ownerId="513845303" transactionname="SELECT" lasttranstarted="2012-06-28T13:38:28.463" XDES="0x80048e50" lockMode="S" schedulerid="7" kpid="12772" status="suspended" spid="154" sbid="0" ecid="0" priority="0" trancount="0" lastbatchstarted="2012-06-28T13:38:28.390" lastbatchcompleted="2012-06-28T13:38:28.380" lastattention="2012-06-28T13:38:27.927" clientapp="TagClerkService" hostname="PMIUSRSTW00008" hostpid="2772" loginname="RICFSE01SAPB1" isolationlevel="read committed (2)" xactid="513845303" currentdb="6" lockTimeout="4294967295" clientoption1="671088672" clientoption2="128056">
            <executionStack>
               <frame procname="adhoc" line="1" sqlhandle="0x020000000d86e30171762b464b35e0923de532c497188b81">  SELECT T0.*  FROM [dbo].[ONNM] T0     </frame>
            </executionStack>
            <inputbuf>  SELECT T0.*  FROM [dbo].[ONNM] T0    </inputbuf>
         </process>
         <process id="process5e31708" taskpriority="0" logused="25240" waitresource="KEY: 6:72057597517103104 (ca73a6396124)" waittime="2031" ownerId="513831818" transactionguid="0xdefde99023405d4a96d101faac79ef96" transactionname="user_transaction" lasttranstarted="2012-06-28T13:38:19.237" XDES="0xd68df950" lockMode="RangeS-S" schedulerid="5" kpid="11564" status="suspended" spid="114" sbid="0" ecid="0" priority="0" trancount="1" lastbatchstarted="2012-06-28T13:38:58.560" lastbatchcompleted="2012-06-28T13:38:58.490" lastattention="2012-06-28T12:48:33.060" clientapp="TagClerkService" hostname="PMIUSRSTL00011" hostpid="2908" loginname="RICFSE01SAPB1" isolationlevel="serializable (4)" xactid="513831818" currentdb="6" lockTimeout="4294967295" clientoption1="671088672" clientoption2="128056">
            <executionStack>
               <frame procname="adhoc" line="1" stmtstart="24" sqlhandle="0x02000000a329a30eb1319f2df684296f889a1613a585b3a0">  SELECT ISNULL(a.U_FSE_ApplicationUsr,a.UserSign) ,a.DocNum ,b.LineNum ,f.IsLotTraced ,h.LotNumber ,b.WhsCode ,n.Bin ,g.Quantity ,b.LineTotal ,i.OnTimeDeliveryDaysEarly ,i.OnTimeDeliveryDaysLate ,i.ReceiptVarianceUnderAllowed ,i.ReceiptVarianceOverAllowed ,k.ItemCode ,d.Revision ,a.Comments ,e.RolledMaterialCost ,e.RolledLaborCost ,e.RolledVariableOverheadCost ,e.RolledFixedOverheadCost ,e.RolledOutsideCost ,ISNULL(c.Quantity, c2.Quantity) ,c.DocumentLineDetailKey /* TODO: Handle serial numbers for blanket deliveries */ ,ISNULL(c.InventoryCode, c2.InventoryCode) ,k.InvntryUom ,r.Resource ,p.ItemName ,CASE WHEN m.MOKey IS NULL THEN NULL ELSE b.U_FSE_STypeItemQty END ,a.DocDate FROM OPDN a LEFT JOIN PDN1 b ON a.DocEntry=b.DocEntry  LEFT JOIN FSE_PurchaseGoodsReceiptLineDetail c ON (b.DocEntry=c.DocumentKey and b.LineNum=c.DocumentLineKey) LEFT JOIN FSE_PurchaseGoodsReceiptDeliveryLineDetail c2 ON (b.DocEntry=c2.DocumentKey and b.LineNum=c2.DocumentLineKey) LEFT JOIN FSE_MO m ON m.DocumentNumber = b.U_FSE_MONumbe     </frame>
               <frame procname="unknown" sqlhandle="0x000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000">  unknown     </frame>
               <frame procname="FSDB00.dbo.SBO_SP_TransactionNotification" line="25" stmtstart="1588" stmtend="2032" sqlhandle="0x030006000a73d75dfe95d60059a000000100000000000000">  exec usp_FSE_HandleSBONotification @object_type, @transaction_type, @num_of_cols_in_key, @list_of_key_cols_tab_del, @list_of_cols_val_tab_del, @error out, @error_message out  -- keep this on one line    --PMI DataTransfer     </frame>
               <frame procname="adhoc" line="1" sqlhandle="0x01000600fd116804e00371a5000000000000000000000000">  EXECUTE SBO_SP_TransactionNotification N&apos;20&apos;,N&apos;A&apos;,1,N&apos;DocEntry&apos;,N&apos;134138&apos;     </frame>
            </executionStack>
            <inputbuf>  EXECUTE SBO_SP_TransactionNotification N&apos;20&apos;,N&apos;A&apos;,1,N&apos;DocEntry&apos;,N&apos;134138&apos;    </inputbuf>
         </process>
      </process-list>
      <resource-list>
         <keylock hobtid="72057598620205056" dbid="6" objectname="FSDB00.dbo.ONNM" indexname="ONNM_PRIMARY" id="lock1aa7d9880" mode="RangeX-X" associatedObjectId="72057598620205056">
            <owner-list/>
            <waiter-list>
               <waiter id="process5e3ae08" mode="RangeX-X" requestType="wait"/>
            </waiter-list>
         </keylock>
         <keylock hobtid="72057598620205056" dbid="6" objectname="FSDB00.dbo.ONNM" indexname="ONNM_PRIMARY" id="lock1aa7d9880" mode="RangeX-X" associatedObjectId="72057598620205056">
            <owner-list>
               <owner id="process5e31708" mode="RangeX-X"/>
            </owner-list>
            <waiter-list>
               <waiter id="process5e45048" mode="S" requestType="wait"/>
            </waiter-list>
         </keylock>
         <keylock hobtid="72057597517103104" dbid="6" objectname="FSDB00.dbo.OITM" indexname="OITM_PRIMARY" id="lock215ce6980" mode="X" associatedObjectId="72057597517103104">
            <owner-list>
               <owner id="process5e3ae08" mode="X"/>
            </owner-list>
            <waiter-list>
               <waiter id="process5e31708" mode="RangeS-S" requestType="wait"/>
            </waiter-list>
         </keylock>
      </resource-list>
   </deadlock>
</deadlock-list>
```

My question is, why was it possible (is it normal) for SPID 78 to acquire a lock on OITM (ca73a6396124) (which happens to represent ItemCode FC1 if I recall correctly) even though it could not acquire a lock on ONNM (36fa3e654c8f). Is my assumption that SQL statements get all-or-none locks incorrect? Does it not hold if the holder of the ONNM lock was a shared lock on a different connection within a transaction that contains multiple connections in the other process? (I think SPID 99 is another connection in the same process as SPID 114.)

This seems to be a really complicated problem to decipher; I don't know if there's a better way of going about deadlock avoidance or finding out what happened here.

Comment: I think that you will get better answers to this on http://dba.stackexchange.com. You can flag your post to migration if you want

Comment: I have copied/migrated the question to http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/20172/all-or-none-exclusive-lock-on-2-sql-tables and voted to close this one as you suggested.

Comment: @BlueMonkMN You should have not, crossposting is not allowed. There's a `flag` link under your question that you should have used.

Comment: @GSerg I did use it. But that didn't put the question on the other forum. Pardon my noob-ness. How is that supposed to happen? Some moderator comes along and moves it? Or it moves when it gets enough votes? Thing I find misleading/lacking is that I'm clicking on a "flag" link which increases the votes to "close" this question, and there's no indication of what's going to happen when the questio gets closed.

Comment: @BlueMonkMN Clicking `Close` is a slow way intended for improper questions. Clicking `Flag` puts a message into the mods queue which will be reviewed at some point (quite quickly actually). You type in that message and ask a mod to move your question without waiting for close votes to accumulate.

Comment: @GSerg I didn't click `Close`; I clicked `Flag` and then selected the option for `It doesn't belong here or is a duplicate` which seemed to be the most appropriate option. I thought I was following the suggestion exactly, but apparently the system has a few options that I wasn't prepared for. So when a question needs to be migrated, I should use `Flag` and request *moderator* attention? I can do that if that's the right way, but it seems excessive to get moderator attention just to move my own question. Does the moderator create the question in the appropriate area then?

Comment: @BlueMonkMN That option is in fact the long route for the `Close` link. You should have selected `Other` and type in your explanation (please move this question as I the owner was advised it's better suited on that site). The `Close` links requires five close votes for the question to get migrated - this is a tool of community moderation (others can migrate your question even if you don't want that). Because in this case we don't want for votes to accumulate, we better use `Flag`. If you wanted to migrate another person's question, you would definitely click `Close` and not `Flag`.

Comment: If you flagged your own question and chose "it doesn't belong here", it got automatically converted into a close vote because you have enough reputation to vote to close (see http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/view-close-votes). You shouldn't have cross-posted it as well, as it potentially creates hassle on both sites - since you voted to close the question, you should have waited for it to be migrated, and in fact you should have tried flagging with a custom message earlier as well. I'm closing this one here since there's not much value in migrating it over and duplicating it.